# justify-content not working in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and have created 4 cards. I want to place the second card to the left. I have added the class justify-content-xl-start to the card but it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding display: flex, flex-direction: column and justify-content: flex-start to my CSS but this doesn't work either. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3

HTML and CSS

```css
.card {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    width: 22rem;
    height: 14rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="card supervisor_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Supervisor</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
      <img src="images/icon-supervisor.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="card team_card d-xl-flex justify-content-xl-start">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Team Builder</h5>
          <p class="card-text">  Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
          <img src="images/icon-team-builder.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="card karma_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Karma</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
      <img src="images/icon-karma.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card calculator_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Calculator</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
      <img src="images/icon-calculator.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `margin: 0 auto;` line in the `.card` CSS is setting the right and left margins of the `card` to be `auto`, which horizontally centers it. You can add the Bootstrap class `mx-0` to [control spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) and set both `margin-left` and `margin-right` to 0.

```css
.card {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    width: 22rem;
    height: 14rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="card supervisor_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Supervisor</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
      <img src="images/icon-supervisor.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="card team_card d-xl-flex justify-content-xl-start mx-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Team Builder</h5>
          <p class="card-text">  Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
          <img src="images/icon-team-builder.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="card karma_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Karma</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
      <img src="images/icon-karma.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card calculator_card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Calculator</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
      <img src="images/icon-calculator.svg" class="card-img" alt="icon supervisor">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I was able to fix the problem myself by adding an outer div to each are card and add the  justify-content: flex-start class to it.

Comment: @becky, please post and accept an answer to resolve this post. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @isherwood no one helped me fix the problem,  so why would I pick the best answer when there is one?

Comment: You would post your own. There's nothing preventing you from doing that, which is why I suggested it. :)

Comment: @becky Please also note my answer provides an adequate solution to your issue using the sample code that you provided in the original question. Running the code snippet in my answer shows that the solution does work. If the solution did not work for you, it is indicative that your question is unclear or is missing additional context.